# Laravel Eloquent relationship - Get titles and values from another table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have defined my current database schema as below in laravel-8 ecommerce website.

**attributes table**

title -> string

**attribute_values table**

attribute_id -> foreign key of attributes table

value-> string

**attribute_values_to_products Table**

product_id -> foreign key of products table

attribute_id -> foreign key of attributes table

attribute_value_id -> foreign key of attribute_values table

**Products model**

```
public function attributes(){
        return $this->hasMany(AttributeValueToProducts::class,'product_id','id');
    }
```

in Controller,

```
$productData= Products::where('slug',$slug)
                        ->first();
    dd($productData->attributes);
```

this give me attribute_id, value_id from attribute_values_to_products table but how to get corresponding title name from other table?

How it's possible that get attribute title from *attribute* table and value field of *attribute_values* table when i try to get attributes of the product?

I am new here in laravel 8.

*Thanks in advance*

Comment: Do you want a one-to-many relationship or a many-to-many relationship? As the structure of you database is atm you've got a many-to-many, and need to use `belongsToMany()` instead of `hasMany()`

Comment: Yes i have many to many relationship. i have used attribute_values_to_products as pivot table where i have attribute_id and value_id field stored i need get title of their from other table. how is it possbile with **belongsToMany()**?

Comment: In that case you need `belongsToMany()` . But still you have to look at your db structure. The attribute id should not be in the pivot table i think.